# Regex and Octal Characters

Tags: python, regex, string, octal

I'm attempting to write a regex that captures octal characters.

For example, if the line I'm comparing to my regex is:

```
char x = '\077';
```

I want my regex to capture `'\077'`

I attempted to do this via the re module and a regex of the form:

```
"'\\[0-7]{1-3}'"
```

But this doesn't capture the octal character.  How can octal characters be identified using regex in Python?

Edit:

As an example of what I mean, consider the C code:

```
char x = '\077'; 
printf("%c", x);
```

I would like to capture `'\077'` from the first line.

Edit:

After testing some of the suggestions in this thread, I have a case that works.  I realize that after adding the octal regex to a larger regex, I needed to prefix with r for raw input, or escape each backslash, for a total of four backslashes.

For example, both of these solve the problem:

```
regex = re.compile(r"\s*("                  
                        r"'\\0[0-7]{1,2}'"          # octal
                        "|[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*"    # identifer
                        ")")
regex.findall(line)
```

and

```
regex = re.compile(r"\s*("                  
                        "'\\\\0[0-7]{1,2}'"         # octal
                        "|[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*"    # identifer
                        ")")
regex.findall(line)
```

Which will produce `'\077'` if line is: `char = '\077';`

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Octal is a number, base 8. It's not a character.

Comment: Try [this code](http://ideone.com/ecLvpp)

Comment: @stribizhev..the range is `[0-9]` ..that's a decimal range not octal, no?

Comment: I think `r"'\\0[0-7]{2}'"` is what you need. See the [updated code](http://ideone.com/ecLvpp)

Comment: @stribizhev This still doesn't work for lines read from stdin via the command line.

Comment: I think this should the trick to convert to raw string: `s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\")` ?

Comment: Well, I tried to read from stdin, and [it works](http://ideone.com/lqqUWb)...

Comment: @VictorBrunell: If you are using the code like `python myscript.py 'char x = \'\077\''` it might work (with single quotes). Also, note that Bash considers ``\`` an escape sequence start and doesn't let it through as an argument, but *cmd* doesn't and lets it through, which yields different behavior in different OSes.

Comment: @VictorBrunell .. Please, provide any feedback to close this question and accept the answer that fits you the most, however, if you feel none of the below is right for you, please do edit your question with more details.

Comment: @IronFist I updated my post.  Please check it out and let me know what you think.

Comment: @stribizhev Feedback added.

Comment: So, my suggestion is right, but you accepted anubhava's

Comment: @stribizhev I don't think I can accept a suggestion as an answer.  Am I mistaken about that?  I accepted anubhava's response as it provides similar information.  Basically, marking the regex line with r and escaping backslashes.  I did vote up your suggestion though.

Comment: I could post an answer if you prefer mine. I do not want to post if there are other solutions, and mine might appear unnecessary because the question is unclear. `\\[0-7]{1,3}` matches `\777` - is it a valid octal number? It matches `\0`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your input as **raw string**:

```
>>> str = r"char x = '\077'; \nprintf(\"%c\", x);"
```

Prefix `r` is for defining a raw string.

Then use:

```
>>> print re.findall(ur"'\\[0-7]{1,3}'", str)
["'\\077'"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX5rR7/1)

---

Code to read text from stdin and apply regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re

str = sys.stdin.read()
print re.findall(ur"'\\[0-7]{1,3}'", str)
```

Comment: `[0-9]` or `[0-7]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t undertand exactly what do you want.

If you want to capture the octal code for the character, you can do:

```
s = r"char x = '\077';"
codes = re.findall(r"\\([0-7]{3})", s)
```

But if you want the characters, you must add:

```
characters = [chr(int(c, 8)) for c in codes]
```

If your intention is `bytes` (Python 3):

```
bytes_result = bytes(characters)
```

Or otherwise string:

```
str_result = ''.join(characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x="""char x = '\077';
  printf("%c", x);"""


print oct(ord(re.findall(r"'([^']*)'",x)[0]))
```

Output:`077`

The problem if you want `077` but you have `\077` which python will convert to `?` as this is the value `\077` represents.So you need to get the integer value of `?` and then get the `octal` value.